# find the counts based on year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to populate these values into temp table to get the number of counts year wise and month wise. Also, want to find how many number of users access the table and count of rows in that month and year.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
 CREATE TABLE #form_counts
    (
      [Table name] SYSNAME ,      
      [Year] DATETIME NULL,
      [Month] DATETIME NULL,
      [Num_Of_Users] INT NULL,
      [Last updated] DATETIME NULL ,
      [Rows] INT NULL
    )

 declare @start_date datetime,@end_date datetime
 set @start_date='19990101'
 set @end_date='20140301'

   INSERT INTO #form_counts
   select * from form_counts
```

Comment: Populate from where? Populate with what?

Comment: I want to populate from forms table which has create date time, create username,update date time , update username. I also want to loop the year from 1999 to 2014.

Comment: have you thought about row_number()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

Kindly follow the following steps it will helpful your needs:

Step 1 : Table Creations (form_counts):

```
       --User Table
       CREATE TABLE form_counts 
       ( 
         Projectid varchar(20),
         TaskId Varchar(20),
         Modifieddate smalldatetime,
         users varchar(20)
       )

       --Temp Table
       CREATE TABLE #Form_counts 
   (
     [Project Name]  VARCHAR(20),
     [No. of Rows Used] INT,
     [No. of Years Used] INT,
     [No. of Months Used] INT,
     [No. of  Users Used] INT
   )
```

Step 2 : Inserting data into form_counts table

```
       INSERT INTO form_counts VALUES 
       ('CO123000','0000000','1900-01-01 00:00:00','SYSADMIN'),
   ('CO123000','AD00001','1998-01-10 00:00:00','Admin2'),
   ('CO123000','AD00003','1998-01-10 00:00:00','SYSADMIN'),
   ('CO123000','ADSERVADJR','2013-04-03 15:50:00','SYSADMIN'),
   ('CO123000','COSERVADJR','2013-04-09 17:09:00','SYSADMIN'),
   ('CO123000','DOSERVADJR','2013-05-08 14:28:00','SYSADMIN'),
   ('CO123000','PM00403','1998-02-15 00:00:00','Admin5'),
   ('CO123001','AD00003','1998-01-10 00:00:00','SYSADMIN'),
   ('CO123001','ADSERVADJR','2013-04-09 12:20:00','SYSADMIN'),
   ('CO123001','PM00403','1998-01-10 00:00:00','Admin5'),
   ('CO123001','TS00504','1998-01-10 00:00:00','SYSADMIN')
```

Step 3: `Select * from form_counts`

Step 4 : Execute the Following Query.

```
       Insert into #Form_counts
       SELECT  A.Project [Project Name],
    SUM(A.TRows) [No. of Rows Used],
    SUM(A.TotYearsUsed) [No. of Years Used],
    SUM(A.TotMonthsUsed) [No. of Months Used],
    MAX(DISTINCT A.ToTusers) [No. of Users Used]
       FROM 
    (
    SELECT Projectid [Project],
           COUNT(projectid) [TRows],
           COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(Modifieddate)) [TotYearsUsed] ,
           COUNT(DISTINCT month(Modifieddate)) [TotMonthsUsed],
           COUNT(DISTINCT Users) [TotUsers]
    FROM form_counts 
    GROUP BY Projectid,YEAR(Modifieddate)
    ) A 
       GROUP BY A.Project
       ORDER BY A.Project DESC

Select * from #Form_counts
```

OutPut :

```
Project Name  No. of Rows Used  No. of Years Used  No. of Months Used   No. of Users Used
CO123000            7        3               5                     3
CO123001            4        2               2                 2
```

Please let me know if any concerns.
Thanks,
Srikanth S

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the count use

```
Select Count(Year), Year 
From form_counts 
where year([Last updated]) between 1999 and 2014
    and month([Last updated])=1
```

if you want to loop through the records from the above query, use cursors in SQL